# How to count row by using GROUP mysql bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql

How to count row by using GROUP mysql bind_param ?

Table : `check`

.

```
__________________________
| id | product_id | user |
| 1  |    123     | test |
| 2  |    456     | test |
| 3  |    456     | test |
| 4  |    123     | test |
| 5  |    789     | test |
```

and this is my code

```
<?PHP
$username = "test";
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM check WHERE user = ? GROUP BY product_id';
$statement = $db_mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('s', $username);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$all_product = $row[0];
echo $all_product;
?>
```

When I test code it's show `5` I want to know how can I do for show `3` `group by product_id`

Comment: You should get three rows from that query. Is that what you mean by *"show 5"*? That it shows 5 rows? Is product_id a text column or a numeric column?

Comment: If you  need to show 3 results, Adds `limit 3` after `product_id` , as this  
` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM check WHERE user = ? GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 3 `
Other wise please explain the question clearly

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your SQL query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) FROM check WHERE user = ?
```

this will produce a result of 3

If you wanted one row for each product, then you would do this:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS c FROM check WHERE user = ? GROUP BY product_id
```

which would look like this:

```
| product_id | c  |
|    123     | 2  |
|    456     | 2  |
|    789     | 1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
$statement=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT user,COUNT(*) FROM check GROUP BY product_id");
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these three queries as per your need. It will give you results as shown below.

To get the total of rows with distinct product_id present in table-:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `product_id`) FROM check;
Result-:

COUNT(DISTINCT `product_id`)
3

---

To get the rows with distinct product_id row-:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `product_id`) FROM check GROUP BY `product_id`;
Result-:

COUNT(DISTINCT `product_id`)

1

1

### 1

To get the row with distinct product_id  with the count number of duplicate product_id present in the table -:

SELECT COUNT(`product_id`) FROM check GROUP BY `product_id`
Result-:

COUNT(`product_id`)
2
2
1